# Is there a way to select a columns from a joined table without explicitly listing all columns?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to use JoinSqlBuilder to select a data from one of the joined tables, and can't find a way to do that unless I list all columns from that table. Hopefully I'm missing something and it actually can be done.

This is approximately what I have:

```
var sql = new JoinSqlBuilder<Product, Product>()
.Join<Product, Customer>(src => src.Id, dst => dst.Id)
.Where<Customer>(x => x.Id == Id);
```

and I want to select everything from a product table. The query above throws an exception complaining about column name collisions, so its clearly does a select from both tables.

Edit: In the end I want to have this sql (never mind the design, its not a real thing):

```
   select 
        p.* //<-- This is the piece that I'm struggling with
   from product p inner join customer c on p.id on c.productId
   where blah;
```

Looks like OrmLite want me to explicitly list all columns I want to return, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I'm using 3.9.71 of servicestack. I've not looked at the 4.0 implementation yet.*

I think you have a FK relationship problem with your join. Assuming that a product has a customer FK named (CustID), it'd look like this. Additionally, you'd need a POCO to represent the result set, if you are returning a "combination" of the results. I don't think you'll want to return both "ID" columns, and instead return a FK column.

```
return _factory.Run<ProductCustomer>(conn=>
{
    var jn = new JoinSqlBuilder<Product, Customer>();

    jn = jn.Join<Product, Customer>(srcProd => srcProd.CustId, 
        dstCust => dstCust.Id, // set up join Customer.id -> Product.CustId
        p => new { p.Id, p.OtherField}, // product table fields returned
        c => new { c.Name, c.AddressId}, // customer fields returned
        null, //where clause on the product table
        cust=>cust.Id = customerId // where clause on the customer table
    );

    var sql = jn.ToSQL();

    return conn.FirstOrDefault<ProductCustomer>(sql);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: After your Edit, try this:

```
    // set up join Customer.id -> c.ProductId
    jn = jn.Join<Product, Customer>(srcProd => srcProd.Id, dstCust => dstCust.productId)
        .Where<Customer>(c=>c.Id == custIdParameter);
    var sql = jn.ToSql();
```

You can add a ".Where" again for the

```
Where<Product>(p=>p.id == foo);
```

if you need to add more product with your BLAH. This should get you close.

Comment: uhm, no, there's no foreign keys involved. You have p => new { p.Id, p.OtherField}, which I want to avoid, because the table is quite large. I'll edit the question to show the resulting sql I want.

Comment: Added an edit. Hope this helps. Since your "blah" was still unknown, you can add more .Where as needed

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the SelectAll extension method?

```
var sql = new JoinSqlBuilder<Product, Product>()
.Join<Product, Customer>(src => src.Id, dst => dst.Id)
.SelectAll<Product>()
.Where<Customer>(x => x.Id == Id);
```